# Showing multiple calenders in zenity command

Tags: zenity, calendar

Zenity command provides an option to show calendar to get date input, like

```
    zenity --calendar
```

In some case, we need to get more than one dates as input. i.e., start and end date.

But the zenity calendar does not have any option to show multiple calendars.

So will need to call `zenity --calendar` twice for getting start and end date selector.

Although, it does not provide better experience or workflow, if we show more then 2 calendars forms one by one.

How can we achieve this in zenity or should we look any alternative commands?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to show more than one calendars in single window itself in zenity.

Zenity provides form option, it allows multiple input elements to be shown. Also supports calendar as input element.

It gave me an idea to show multiple calendar in zenity.

See the example below,

```
zenity --forms --text='Give start and end date' --add-calendar='start date' --add-calendar='end date'
```

It will give the selected dates as | separated values.